# Checking hierarchy of null in if statement

Tags: c#, .net

In a complex object like [`OperationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is it safe to write such code:

```
if(OperationContext.Current!=null && 
   OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext !=null && 
   OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity !=null)
```

Or do I need to separate the code to three `if` statements?

My question is if the `OperationContext.Current` is null I afraid that `OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [&&](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) operator in C# uses [short circuit evalulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) so your code is fine.

What this means is the left-hand side of the condition is evaluated first and if it passes the right-hand side is then evaluated.

Comment: what is circuit evalulation?

Comment: @ilayzeidman I have explained in my answer. Also, the links I have provided will give you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 3):

It is safe. Right side of `&&` is evaluated only if left side is `true`.

Here is the [MSDN explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx):

> The operation
>
> ```
> x && y
> ```
>
> corresponds to the operation
>
> ```
> x & y
> ```
>
> except that if x is false, y is not evaluated, because the result of
>   the AND operation is false no matter what the value of y is. This is
>   known as "short-circuit" evaluation.

Comment: so the order is important?

Comment: @ilayzeidman, yes it is. If you swap the operands and `Current` is null, you will have an exception

Answer (score 1):

It won't, please take a look at the definition of the *&&* operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx. If the first part is false, the second one is simply not evaluated.

Your code would throw that exception if you used the *&* operator.